# Spring MVC with EXT JS error: DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc, extjs

I am trying to get a simple EXT JS form to appear on my tomcat but i am getting the following error:

```
17-Apr-2012 10:46:09 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/helloworld/service/web/js  /restful.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'rest'
17-Apr-2012 10:46:09 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/helloworld/service/web/js/restful.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'rest'
```

web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>
classpath:/application-context.xml
</param-value>
</context-param>


<!-- This listener will load other application context file in addition to 
        rest-servlet.xml -->
<listener>
<listener-class>
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

rest-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.fexco.helloworld.web" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
          <property name="messageConverters">
                 <list>
                       <ref bean="jsonConverter" />
                 </list>
          </property>
   </bean>

   <bean id="jsonConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
          <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json" />
   </bean>

   <bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I am calling the restful.css and restful.js classes from the index.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"%>

<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/webapp/js/restful.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/webapp/js/restful.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>This is used to display EXT objects</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

directory structure

[image: this is the structure of my directory]

I cant seem to solve this error, my index.jsp is appearing on the page alright but no EXT form is appearing, I have looked at similar problems online and all there solutions are in mine at the moment so this not the same errors.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Can you show your directory structure?

Comment: i just added the directory structure there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you refer to your static files (`.js` and `.css`) by relative paths. It doesn't make sense, because location of these files doesn't depend on location of the page being displayed.

You need to use absolute paths instead. You can use `<c:url>` to construct absolute paths that include context path of your application (so, they're correct no matter where your application is deployed):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value = '/js/restful.css' />" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value = '/js/restful.js' />"></script>
```

Comment: still not getting the form to appear on the screen but this solved the error anyway... cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/js/restful.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/restful.js"></script>
```